# Determining where the mouse has clicked on a HScrollBar

Tags: c#

I have a program where the columns can be different widths. It would make sense (for this program) as you scrolled, to move left or right the distance that would show in its entirety the next column to be shown.

To do this, I need to assign SmallChange when the user clicks on one of the arrows on the scroll bar. Sure, I can use OldValue, NewValue to work out the travel direction of the scrollbar, but I still don't know whether to set the movement to a whole page or just a row.

How is this normally handled?

Any clues greatly appreciated.

Comment: That will not be an easy task, inherently you have no way to know where it has clicked, only thing what comes to my mind is to use a NativeWindow, hook to the WndProc, listen for click messages and check if they are in the bounds of the scroll bar, and if they are then do your processing (rescale the scrollbar and set the value) and not to pump up the message

Comment: Well that explains why a Google search was not forthcoming with an answer. Looks like a job for the 'Too hard basket'. I might just set an arbitrary amount and leave it at that. In this instance it is not that important, but would have been a nice bit of polish for the program. Thank you for your time Gusman in replying to this question.